# String.Split issues

Tags: c#, split, filestream

The strings I try to initialize with `temp.Split` results are always null.
`G.ReadLine()` is simply a `"name%path"` format. I also changed the encoding to unicode for certainty that there is no encoding difference between file and program.

Here is the relevant fragment:

```
StreamReader g = new StreamReader(path + "database.txt",Encoding.Unicode);

do
{
     String temp;
     temp = g.ReadLine();
     //wr.WriteLine(temp);
     try
     {
           names[ii] = temp.Split('%')[0];
```

Thank you for help

Comment: you mean a fragment of the relevant code, right?

Comment: `Split` method never returns null. Do you mean `ReadLine` returns null?

Comment: Can you confirm that `temp` contains the string 'name%path'?

Comment: Well without any additional information about the text you are reading and a full compilable examples its gone hard to help you

Comment: Whats the error you're actually getting?

Comment: WhoDat4%C:\Users\practica\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\telekinectics\telekinectics\FramesWhoDat4.bmp this is a line in the file. temp has the correct value

Answer (score 1):

So now we found the route of the problem.
The instantiation of names was wrong.

Instead of

```
string[] names = null;
```

Something like

```
string[] names = new string[5];
```

must be used. The Problem here is that you have to now before how many strings the array will contain.
I recommand you to use an List of strings so something like that:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
```

and then use it with:

```
names.Add(temp.Split('%')[0]);
```

Comment: @Andrei Ciurea have you tried my code, does it work? At least we know then, if its a Split Issue or not.

Comment: yes, I tried it, however the issue is the same, names[ii] is still null. #BugFinder The exception i get is of course NullReferenceException but I caught it for further debugging.

Comment: How do yo have names declared?

Comment: #JoshuadV as a global variable: String[] names = null;

Comment: I editet my answer completely, it should work now i guess :)

Comment: #JoshuadV I tried both the temp.Substring() and the declaration you suggested and they didn't change anything. I can provide any information about the code, i didn't post the whole code because it is huge and irrelevant to this specific segment

Comment: #JoshuadV I also tried with List before the actual post

Comment: The important thing is not that you use List, the important one is that u instantiate it with a new Object of that type (so NOT null). Have you done that? Show me your instantiation with List please.

Comment: The problem is that even if i try to print to console or file the temp.Split('%')[0] or the temp.Substring(0, temp.IndexOf('%')) i get nothing. Once again, temp HAS the correct value

Comment: Received the Code and will have a look at it. well No, just received the txt File. I need your C# Code or Project.

Answer (score 0):

`"name%path".Split('%')[0]` returns `"name"`

So the problem is not `Split` function, but in `temp` which value does not have `"name%path"` pattern.

Comment: temp is not null, it has the "name%path" type of value